# cant find last row in particular range in google app script as sheet has data on other columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets with name 'copy' and 'paste' in copy sheet there are only three column which I need to paste in paste sheet but in paste sheet there multiple column which already has a data I want to copy sheet data in paste sheet data in column A,B and C so I can't find last row as paste sheet has data in other column.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your script

```
Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function(col){
  var lastRow = this.getLastRow();
  if (col == null){col='A'}
  var range = this.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }  
};
```

then replace `.getLastRow()` by `.getLastDataRow()` (add +1 to get the first empty cell)